# Use data to name column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables and I want to run a query where I use a value in one of the tables to change what column dateadd uses.

```
table1
id      value    date1        date2          date3  
-------|-------|------------|------------|-----------|
1      | 10    | 04/03/2018 | 04/03/2017 |01/03/2016 |
2      | 1     | 04/03/2018 | 05/03/2015 |02/03/2018 |
3      | 2     | 04/03/2016 | 06/03/2016 |03/03/2018 |
4      | 1     | 04/03/2015 | 07/03/2018 |04/03/2017 |
5      | 2     | 04/03/2017 | 09/03/2018 |05/03/2019 |

table2
id      value   
-------|-------|
1      | date1 |
2      | date3 |
3      | date3 |
4      | date2 |
5      | date1 |
```

The normal way to do ID 1 would be something like `dateadd(month,10,date1)`. I'm not sure how to do this without me writing it every single time though.

```
select *
from table1
join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
where DATEADD(month, table1.value, table1.[table2.value]) between '1/1/18' and '12/31/18'
```

Comment: Have you tried a case statement?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Twelfth, yes I have tried a case statement, problem is that the actual table I'm using has 10 different date columns. Just trying to see if there is an easier way to do it without having to write them 10 times.

Comment: You could write a procedure to do so with dynamic sql.

Comment: Ah, yes...the case statement will get rather long with that many cases.  I have 3 options to go with in these cases.  1. case statement.  gets bulky.  2. Dynamic SQL.  Comes with it's own issues (including security).  3. 'Unpivot' your table and work with it from there.  Unpivot would be to change the table so it's ID, date_column_name, then date (date column name holds 'date1' and the sort, then you join that to table2 to get the date you want).  The unpivot can be done on the fly, but may become a long query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this as theory, you're actually the first questioner I can try to apply it with.  The idea is to unpivot your data and then join on the value column.

```
select id,column_name,value
from table1 t1
unpivot (
value
for column_name in (date1,date2,date3,date4,date5,date6,date7,date8,date9,date10)
) a
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t2.value = a.column_name
where t2.value
between '1/1/18' and '12/31/18'
```

I can't guarantee that will work and am curious how it does for you.

Answer (score 3):

Twelfth's answer is correct. I just wanted to see if his theory works, and it does - here's a working implementation.

```
declare @table1 table (id int, value int, date1 date, date2 date, date3 date)
declare @table2 table (id int, colname varchar(5))

insert into @table1 values (1,10,'04/03/2018','04/03/2017','01/03/2016')
insert into @table1 values (2,1 ,'04/03/2018','05/03/2015','02/03/2018')
insert into @table1 values (3,2 ,'04/03/2016','06/03/2016','03/03/2018')
insert into @table1 values (4,1 ,'04/03/2015','07/03/2018','04/03/2017')
insert into @table1 values (5,2 ,'04/03/2017','09/03/2018','05/03/2019')

insert into @table2 values (1, 'date1')
insert into @table2 values (2, 'date3')
insert into @table2 values (3, 'date3')
insert into @table2 values (4, 'date2')
insert into @table2 values (5, 'date1')

select id, colname, newdate
from
(
    select sq.id, sq.colname, dateadd(month, sq.value, sq.dn) as newdate
    from @table1 t1
    unpivot
    (
        dn for colname in ([date1], [date2], [date3])
    )sq
    inner join @table2 t2 on sq.id = t2.id and sq.colname = t2.colname
)sq where newdate between '1/1/2018' and '12/31/2018'
```

Output:

```
id  colname newdate
2   date3   2018-03-03
3   date3   2018-05-03
4   date2   2018-08-03
```

Comment: Ha, never had anyone proof a theory of mine.  ty and +1